# Görtz-Wedhorn Lemma 3.20

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am trying to understand the proof of Lemma 3.20 in Görtz-Wedhorn Algebraic Geometry I. They use it to show that Spec($A$) is Noetherian iff $A$ is Noetherian.
[image]

I do not understand some details:

1. Why $N_{f_i}=M_{f_i}$?
2. How do we get that localizations vanish from $N_{f_i}=M_{f_i}$?

I also do not get where the hypothesis Spec($A$)=$\cup_{i=1}^n D(f_i)$ (or equivalently $A=(f_1, \ldots f_n$ ) ) is used. I think that this has to do with my first question, but I am not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. $N_{f_i}$ is a $A_{f_i}$ module so you can multiply elements with $1/{f_i}$. 2. Vanishing of a module is a local property. So you just have to see why $M/N$ localized at a prime of $A$ vanishes.

Comment: That is precisely what I am asking, i dont get why $(M/N)_{\mathfrak{p}}$ vanishes.

Comment: You have to use the fact that $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is convered by the $D(f_i)$. Pick a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}\in \mathrm{Spec}(A)$. Then $\mathfrak{p} \in D(f_i)$ for some $f_i$. Then $(M/N)_\mathfrak{p}=\left((M/N)_{f_i})\right)_\mathfrak{p}=\left(M_{f_i}/N_{f_i}\right)_\mathfrak{p}=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, the $m_{ij}$, for a given $i$, generate the localization of $M$ at $f_i$, and $N$ contains *all* of the $m_{ij}$, so its localization at $f_i$ must contain $M_{f_i}$ since it contains a generating set for it. On the other hand, all the $m_{ij}$ lie in $M$, so certainly $N \subseteq M$ and hence $N_{f_i}  \subseteq M_{f_i}$, and so they must be equal.

For your second question, what you need to do is to deduce from the fact that $M_{f_i} = N_{f_i}$ for each $i \in I$ that $M_{\mathfrak p} = N_{\mathfrak p}$ for every prime ideal $\mathfrak p$. This is where you need to use the hypothesis about the $D(f_i)$ covering $\text{Spec}(A)$.

If you can see how to deduce that, the final part of the argument uses the fact that localization is exact so that $(M/N)_{\mathfrak p} = M_{\mathfrak p}/N_{\mathfrak p}=0$ and hence $M/N$ is annihilated when you localise at any prime ideal, which forces it to be zero.

(This argument may not be the most efficient actually -- you can conclude $M/N =0$ just using the localizations $(M/N)_{f_i}$ for $i \in I$ directly, rather than going via the prime ideals, but probably they wanted to use $M_{\mathfrak p}$ to encourage readers to think of the stalks of the associated coherent sheaf or something.)